# Suspend fails but /lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend works

Tags: suspend

I cannot seem to make the system go to sleep properly (more details later) since a few days. This is since after an update to a bunch of Nvidia drivers, but staied in place after an update to 22.04.

However doing this:

```
sudo /lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend
```

works perfectly, and on the other hand this:

```
sudo systemctl suspend
```

fails in the same way so I guess that the failure must happen between the two.

Specifically, the failure looks like this:

- it tries to suspend
- bounces back to a login screen
- then logs into a new session or
- sometimes bounces again to a login screen
- and from there to a new session
- and sometimes it just gets stuck on a black screen with arrow cursor, so I have to force reboot

The machine is a Lenovo ThinkPad P50 i7-6820HQ and there's more than enough disk space to go by.

Memory:

```
MemTotal:       32235340 kB
```

and disk:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.1G  3.5M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/sda6       121G   27G   88G  23% /
tmpfs            16G   16K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  458G  202G  233G  47% /home
/dev/sda8        73G  8.9G   61G  13% /data
/dev/sda5       512M   24K  512M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.1G  116K  3.1G   1% /run/user/1000
```

What should I look into to pinpoint the issue?